# Complex MySQL query for specific problemm

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have searched and gone through the available topics similar to mine. But, failed to find that satisfies my requirements. Hence, posting it here.

I have four tables as follows:

```
"Organization" table:
--------------------------------
| org_id       | org_name      |
| 1            | A             |
| 2            | B             |
| 3            | C             |

"Members" table:
----------------------------------------------
| mem_id       | mem_name     | org_id       |
| 1            | mem1         | 1            |
| 2            | mem2         | 1            |
| 3            | mem3         | 2            |
| 4            | mem4         | 3            |

"Resource" table:
--------------------------------
| res_id       | res_name      | res_prop    |
| 1            | resource1     | prop-1      |
| 2            | resource2     | prop-2      |
| 3            | resource3     | prop-3      |
| 4            | resource4     | prop-4      |
| 5            | resource1     | prop-5      |
| 6            | resource2     | prop-6      |
```

A constraint of UNIQUE INDEX (res_name, res_prop) is applied in the above table.

```
"member-resource" table:
--------------------------------------------
| sl_no        | mem_id     | res_id       |
| 1            | 1          | 1            |
| 2            | 1          | 2            |
| 3            | 2          | 1            |
| 4            | 4          | 3            |
| 5            | 3          | 4            |
| 6            | 2          | 3            |
| 7            | 4          | 3            |
| 8            | 1          | 5            |
| 9            | 1          | 6            |
```

I want to find out the distinct `res_name` from `Resource` table that have more than one `res_prop` for a specific organization. For example, expected output for organization `A` would be as follows:

```
| res_name       | res_prop_count       |
| resource1      | 2                    |
| resource2      | 2                    |
```

Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLS (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: Why is `resource2` in the result? It only has one `mem_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing things like this you should build your query up logically, so to start get all your resources and props from organisation A

```
SELECT  r.res_name,
        r.res_prop
FROM    Resource r
        INNER JOIN `member-resource` mr
            ON mr.res_id = r.res_id
        INNER JOIN Members m
            ON m.mem_id = mr.mem_id
        INNER JOIN Organization o
            ON o.org_id = m.org_id
WHERE   o.org_name = 'A'
```

Then you can start thinking about how you want to filter it, so you want to find resource names that have more than one different res_prop, so you need to group by res_name, and apply a HAVING clause to limit it to res_names with more than one distinct res_prop:

```
SELECT  r.res_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT r.res_prop) AS res_prop_count
FROM    Resource r
        INNER JOIN `member-resource` mr
            ON mr.res_id = r.res_id
        INNER JOIN Members m
            ON m.mem_id = mr.mem_id
        INNER JOIN Organization o
            ON o.org_id = m.org_id
WHERE   o.org_name = 'A'
GROUP BY r.res_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.res_prop) > 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f1a6/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are looking for, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT          Resource.res_name,
                COUNT(DISTINCT Resource.res_prop) AS res_prop_count
FROM            Resource
INNER JOIN      member_resource
USING           (res_id)
INNER JOIN      Members
USING           (mem_id)
INNER JOIN      Organization
USING           (org_id)
WHERE           Organization.org_name = 'A'
GROUP BY        res_name
HAVING          res_prop_count > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**If you have Organization ID then use the query below:**

```
SELECT r.res_name, COUNT(DISTINCT r.res_prop) res_prop_count 
FROM member-resource mr 
INNER JOIN Resource r ON mr.res_id = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN Members m ON mr.mem_id = r.mem_id 
WHERE m.org_id = 1
GROUP BY r.res_id HAVING res_prop_count > 1;
```

**If you have Organization name then use the query below:**

```
SELECT r.res_name, COUNT(DISTINCT r.res_prop) res_prop_count 
FROM member-resource mr 
INNER JOIN Resource r ON mr.res_id = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN Members m ON mr.mem_id = r.mem_id 
INNER JOIN Organization o ON m.org_id = o.org_id
WHERE m.org_name = 'A'
GROUP BY r.res_id HAVING res_prop_count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
    res_name, count(res_prop) as res_prop_count
from
    Resource
where
    res_id in (select 
            res_id
        from
            member_resource
        where
            mem_id in (select 
                    mem_id
                from
                    Members
                where
                    org_id = (select 
                            org_id
                        from
                            Organization
                        where
                            org_name = 'A'))) group by res_name
```